# Proof of inequivalence right and left spinor representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, spinors

I'm asked to prove the inequivalence of $\Lambda_L$ and $\Lambda_R$ for transformations close to the identity. So I start with the definition
\begin{equation}
\Lambda_R=S\Lambda_LS^{-1}
\end{equation}
and I should show that no $S$ matrix exist.
So I proceeded doing the following
\begin{equation}
\Lambda_R=S\Lambda_LS^{-1}\implies \exp{\bigg({\frac{\vec\sigma}{2}(i\vec\theta-\vec\phi)}\bigg)}=S \exp{\bigg({\frac{\vec\sigma}{2}(i\vec\theta+\vec\phi)}\bigg)}S^{-1}
\end{equation}
and passing to the infinitesimal form I got
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{1}+\frac{\vec\sigma}{2}(i\vec\theta-\vec\phi)=S\Big(\mathbb{1}+\frac{\vec\sigma}{2}(i\vec\theta+\vec\phi)\Big)S^{-1}\implies \frac{\vec\sigma}{2}(i\vec\theta-\vec\phi)=S\Big(\frac{\vec\sigma}{2}(i\vec\theta+\vec\phi)\Big)S^{-1}
\end{equation}

From here I'm not quite sure on how to proceed. I've thought of something but all that comes to my mind involves splitting and comparing the different members and I'm sure it's the wrong way. 
Any clue?

Comment: You seem to have lost a minus sign when moving to the infinitesimal form

Comment: Such an identity would have to hold for all $\vec\theta,\vec\phi$. Consider e.g. the two particular cases $\vec\theta=\vec\phi$ and $\vec\theta=-\vec\phi$ to arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: Hi AFT, thanks for your answer. I'm confused at this point, the matrix $S$ has to be the same matrix for every element $g$ of the group? Or it's such that $S=S(g)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two representations $\Lambda$ and $\Lambda'$ of $G$ are *equivalent* if there is a non singular transformation $S$ such that $S \Lambda'(g)= \Lambda(g)S\,\, \forall g \in G$.

So yes, the matrix must be the same for all elements. To prove that they are not equivalent, you can pick some "nice" elements which give you conditions that cannot be satisfied by any $S$. An example was given in the comments.